# Contents keep flowing out of the div whose height is set to 100%

Tags: css

I am trying to keep my header text inside the header picture, which is set to height: 100%.
When I shrink the height of the website, texts start flowing out of the wrapper..
I want the texts to stay inside the header picture. In other words, I want the pic to be big enough to keep the texts inside it regardless of the browser height, even though I set the height equal to 100%. I already tried setting min-height..

If you dont know what I mean, please try to shrink the height of your browser here...

http://nycmultifamilyloans.com/

How do I fix this?

So far, I have:

```
<div id="headerwrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row centered headertext">

                <h1>WE PROVIDE MULTIFAMILY, MIXED USE, AND COMMERCIAL MORTGAGES</h1>
                <h2>in New York City</h2>
                    <p>
                        GEORGE O'CONNOR <br/>
                        917-805-8851<br/>
                        GTOCONNOR@NYCMULTIFAMILYLOANS.COM
                    </p>
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- container -->

    </div><!-- headerwrap -->

    #headerwrap {
       position: relative;
    }



    html, body, #headerwrap{
        height: 100%;
    }

    #headerwrap .container {

        background: url(../img/header.jpg) no-repeat center top;
        margin-top: -10px;
        padding-top:20px;
        text-align:center;
        background-attachment: relative;
        background-position: center center;
       height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        -webkit-background-size: 100%;
        -moz-background-size: 100%;
        -o-background-size: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;

        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .headertext {
         position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nice looking site!
If you are willing to specify a min height in pixels simply do this:

```
#headerwrap {
    position: relative;
    min-height:450px;
}
```

You could probably do something more responsive with min-height too.